# Find diameter of tree if for each node, parent pointer is given

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have searched this question here but could not see any question for optimized diameter for a binary tree.

```
How do we find diameter of a binary tree if parent pointer to each node is given.

Definition of tree diameter is : Longest distance between two nodes of tree.
```

> EDIT:: Please use parent pointer to find the diameter. I am aware of
>   finding diameter using recursion, and that is done by finding max of
>   (left dia,right dia and height of tree)

Node structure is as follows
class Node{
Node left;
Node right;
Node parentPointer;
int  data;

}

Comment: What do you mean that the parent pointer is given? Do you have a list of all leaves? That is not a very logical data structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify what parent pointer has to do with diameter. If you define diameter as the maximal distance between any two nodes than it's irrelevant which node is the designated parent. If, on the other hand, there's a distinction, such as the parent node is the source and the other nodes are drains, then you are probably looking for the maximal distances from any node to the source, rather then the tree's diameter.

That said, you could solve either problem by running breadth-first search (BFS). If you are looking for the distance from the dedicated parent run BFS and mark each node with the distance to the parent.

If, on the other hand, you are looking for the tree diameter run BFS twice: 1st start from any node you like and find the furthest; then start with the furthest node and find the one furthest from it. It so happens that the distance from "the furthest node from any given node" to "the furthest node from the furthest one you just found" gives you the tree's diameter.

Answer (score 1):

This code from [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) shows how to compute the diameter of a binary time in O(n).

However, there is no need for a parent pointer so perhaps I have misunderstood your question?

```
/*The second parameter is to store the height of tree.
   Initially, we need to pass a pointer to a location with value
   as 0. So, function should be used as follows:

   int height = 0;
   struct node *root = SomeFunctionToMakeTree();
   int diameter = diameterOpt(root, &height); */
int diameterOpt(struct node *root, int* height)
{
  /* lh --> Height of left subtree
      rh --> Height of right subtree */
  int lh = 0, rh = 0;

  /* ldiameter  --> diameter of left subtree
      rdiameter  --> Diameter of right subtree */
  int ldiameter = 0, rdiameter = 0;

  if(root == NULL)
  {
    *height = 0;
     return 0; /* diameter is also 0 */
  }

  /* Get the heights of left and right subtrees in lh and rh
    And store the returned values in ldiameter and ldiameter */
  ldiameter = diameterOpt(root->left, &lh);
  rdiameter = diameterOpt(root->right, &rh);

  /* Height of current node is max of heights of left and
     right subtrees plus 1*/
  *height = max(lh, rh) + 1;

  return max(lh + rh + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in question, that parent pointer has to be used. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Well, you could use the parent pointers to reconstruct left and right pointers in O(n) and then use the original algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

http://leisurehours.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/find-the-diameter-of-a-tree/

Assuming that we are given pointer to any node of the tree.

Do the BFS (breadth first Search) on the given node and find a node having maximum distance from the given node. The node having maximum distance from the given node will be a leaf node. Lets call it node1
Now again apply the BFS on the node1 and find the maximum distance of any node from node1 . This distance is the diameter of the tree. Because node1 is a leaf of tree and BFS finds the shortest distance from node1 ( a leaf ) to all other nodes in tree. Clearly the node farthest from node1 will be a leaf and hence we will get the diameter of tree.